# Redirect from a sub directory to a sub domain with post/get parameters intact

Tags: .htaccess

I have set up a .htaccess file that redirects requests to a sub directory `example.com/app/` to a sub domain `app.example.com`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://app.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works, but when a request with post parameters are sent to `example.com/app/mcp.php` the url is redirected to `app.example.com/mcp.php` without the post parameters.

My question is

- How do I redirect request from a sub directory to a sub domain with the post/get parameters?

Comment: It looks like this might be possible http://stackoverflow.com/a/1562986/58456

Comment: @Gerben it is not possible as the client would have to resent the POST. And as far as I know no clients resent posts on redirect.

Comment: 307 will resent the POST. If you had at least tried it out, you would have seen that. Stop wasting my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do. the HTTP Spec prevents it. A full description of the problem can be found in this comment 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1562986/58456